# Using php, can I "Import" a text of an textfile which contains variables?

Tags: php, file, variables, text, import

I want to generate a form out of a textfile so that I just need to update mentioned text file instead of the php site. Because I need to know how many entries this form has, I want to use variables. (I know a mySQL database would make it a lot easier but I need to do it without mysql)

My php "Import function" looks like this at the moment, reading the file line by line and thus counting how many elements i'm adding to my form:

```
$file = fopen("test.txt","r");
$AmountOfEntries=0;
$EntryNumber=0;

while(! feof($file)){
    $EntryNumber++;
    $str = fgets($file);
    echo $str;
    $AmountOfEntries++;
}
fclose($file);
```

This is the content of my text file

```
a<input type="checkbox" name="$EntryNumber" id="a" value="This is a"><br>
b<input type="checkbox" name="$EntryNumber" id="b" value="This is b"><br>
c<input type="checkbox" name="$EntryNumber" id="c" value="This is c"><br>
d<input type="checkbox" name="$EntryNumber" id="d" value="This is d"><br>
```

the import itself works, only trouble I have is replacing the variable by its value. I've tried to append it using

```
name="'. $EntryNumber. '"
```

But it didn't work. Also, the reason I store the line in $str first is, me hoping that maybe if it's being "processed" before echoed this would work.
I'm also aware that using an array would be helpful, I've tried that as well, but because I want to write the entire html code of the submitted form back into the txt file, I need the unchecked checkboxes as well, and I failed to determine their states when using an array. So if you have an idea, how I could do it with an array instead of an individual name for each checkbox, that'd be welcome as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you're writing HTML in a text file, loading it into PHP, and then writing it back as HTML?  Why not just inject HTML into .php files at that point?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = 'a<input type="checkbox" name="$EntryNumber" id="a" value="This is a"><br>
b<input type="checkbox" name="$EntryNumber" id="b" value="This is b"><br>
c<input type="checkbox" name="$EntryNumber" id="c" value="This is c"><br>
d<input type="checkbox" name="$EntryNumber" id="d" value="This is d"><br>';

//$str = file_get_contents('test.txt');

$str_array = explode("\r\n", $str);
$AmountOfEntries = count($str_array);
for($EntryNumber = 0; $EntryNumber < $AmountOfEntries; $EntryNumber++)
{
    $str_array[$EntryNumber] = str_replace('"$EntryNumber"', '"'.$EntryNumber.'"', $str_array[$EntryNumber]);
}

var_dump(implode("\r\n", $str_array));
?>
```

Outputs

```
string(254) "a<input type="checkbox" name="0" id="a" value="This is a"><br>
b<input type="checkbox" name="1" id="b" value="This is b"><br>
c<input type="checkbox" name="2" id="c" value="This is c"><br>
d<input type="checkbox" name="3" id="d" value="This is d"><br>"
```

Comment: If I could add one tweak to your solution it would be to include the "" in the replace. `str_replace('"$EntryNumber"', '".$EntryNumber.'"', $str_array[$EntryNumber])`. This will allow for variables named $EntryNumber1 etc.